# How to unit test overloaded constructor for ArgumentNullException where each constructor only has one parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I was making a test for a class which has an overloaded constructor the first taking a single entity and the second takes a list of same type entities.

```
class MyClass
{
      public MyClass(Entity entity)
      {
           if(entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

           // continue initialising.
      }

      public MyClass(IList<Entity> entityList)
      {
            if(entityList == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entityList");

            // continue initialising.
      }
}
```

But of course trying to test each constructer by passing null causes ambiguity on which constructor I want called by the unit test.

Is there any way round this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast null to remove the ambiguity:

```
var c = new MyClass((Entity)null);
var cl = new MyClass((IList<Entity>)null);
```

Comment: This works in Java, too - same syntax.